# Django Jsignature not passing the form.is_valid()

Tags: jquery, django

I am using jsignature:

https://github.com/fle/django-jsignature

I have managed to display the signature pad:

[image: Signatured pad in html]

But when i tried to submit the form. i noticed that it could not pass the is_valid function
and when i tried to printout the errors here is what i get:

```
<ul class="errorlist"><li>signature<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li></ul>
```

Here's my code in view:

```
form = SignatureForm(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():

        signature = form.cleaned_data.get('signature')

        if signature:
            # as an image
            signature_picture = draw_signature(signature)
            # or as a file
            signature_file_path = draw_signature(signature, as_file=True)
    else:

        print(form.errors)
```

Template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>signature</title>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    {{ form.media }}
    <form action="." method="POST">

        {% for field in form %}
            {{ field.label_tag }}
            {{ field }}
            <span style="color:red">{{ field.errors }}</span>
        {% endfor %}
        <input type="submit" value="Save"/>
        {% csrf_token %}
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from jsignature.forms import JSignatureField


class SignatureForm(forms.Form):
    signature = JSignatureField()
```

Comment: Can you share your form and template? Can you check that all the JS is loading?

Comment: Added the form and template. I'm sure it is loading the needed js files by checking it's page source.

Comment: Is jsignature in your INSTALLED_APPS and have you run collectstatic?

Comment: Yes, it is in my installed apps. Nope, didn't run collectstatic. Do I need to do that? because I was testing it out for development.

Comment: Check your devtools console for any errors?

Comment: Didn't get any errors, but I think hidden values were not being read. Because it was input type="hidden"

Comment: hidden inputs are still passed in the form data. Can you inspect `request.POST` to confirm it's there?

Comment: Try upgrading jquery, you're on a very old version

Comment: Thanks, upgraded my jquery to a newer version and it worked. @Iain Shelvington put your answer so I can mark it correct. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

In your view SignatureForm(request.POST, request.FILES).

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.